# how can I do Simultaneous process in kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I want to show gif for 10 minutes and simultaneously scan some file in kivy ?
but I don't Know how.
Anyone Know That how can I do it ?

I want to click on button in kv file and show gif then simultaneously start scan.

Comment: [This post should help you out. I had the same problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67175672/kivy-loading-animation-for-long-function-avoid-freeze)

Answer (score 0):

For this, I believe you need to use the async module.

[this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t5Bo1Je9EmE) should help (I was just learning about the same )